# Using Spring JpaDaoSupport with Appengine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine

I've been using Objectify for Datastore persistence, however for some reason I needed to do stuff in JPA however I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JPA PersistenceProvider returned null EntityManagerFactory - check your JPA provider setup!
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1504)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 51 more
```

**DAO Implementation code:**

```
@Repository("accountDao")
//@Transactional
public class AccountDaoImpl extends JpaDaoSupport implements AccountDao {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AccountDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    public AccountDaoImpl(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        super.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    // DAO crud function code omitted

}
```

[servlet-context.xml](http://pastebin.com/QSuTNcmt) `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/`

[persistence.xml](http://pastebin.com/KWGUTUCt) `src/main/resources/META-INF`

Comment: I pasted the xml config via pastebin because its too long to be displayed here, and I made the paste never expires so that should do it. Also, I have included all the beans just in case there me be something wrong in the xml file.